# Angular Download File From Amazon S3 URL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-sce

I am unable to download an image from an Amazon S3 URL, with an anchor tag in Angular. What am I missing?

URL

```
  https://s3.amazonaws.com/nationalrx/card/national_test.png
```

HTML

```
  div(ng-bind-html="trustedHtml")
```

CONTROLLER

```
  $scope.html = '<a target="_self" ng-href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/nationalrx/card/national_test.png" download>Download NOW</a>';
  $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
```

CONFIG

```
  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel|blob|):/);
```

$sceProvider.enabled(false) did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives like ng-href are not executed by ng-bind-html. Just use `href`: there is no reason to use `ng-href`.

I would also avoid using ng-bind-html, BTW. Why don't you make the link part of your template, and store only the URL in the scope variable?

Comment: I created a simple [Angular version](http://jsbin.com/nexawu/22/edit?html,js,output). Looking deeply for the human error, but can't find it.

Comment: Here's a simplified, corrected version: http://jsbin.com/cuxorawiju/edit?html,js,output. Key points: no need for $sce, sanitize or anything. But ng-app="app" must be on one of the enclosing elements.

Comment: Genius is simple. Thank you